# What does rm --preserve-root prevent exactly?

Tags: linux, rm

Modern rm by default has the `--preserve-root` option enabled, but what exactly does this prevent?

I understand it will prevent `rm -r /` (right?)

but does it prevent

```
cd /
rm *
```

or

```
rm /*
```

for example? The man page and help are not clear, annoying for such an important and dangerous command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it yourself with `-i` so nothing gets deleted.

```
rm -ri /
rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on '/'
rm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe
```

but

```
cd /
rm -ri *
rm: descend into directory 'bin/'?
```

Note that the second would not delete files and directories that match the `/.*` glob.